# return variables from array using a function

Tags: php, mysql

I retrieve data from database using this query:

`SELECT * FROM  tickets_departement_groups WHERE group_id = '{$user_group}'`

`$user_group` is already defined, and I fetch the data using `mysql_fetch_array`, like this:

```
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
    return $row['departement_id'];
}
```

All this is under a function called `get_departement_id()`, So when I do `echo get_departement_id();`
it prints last departement ID, but I have many of them. What I want to do is to output all the department IDs for a given query.

Comment: It's spelt "department".

Comment: I couldn't help but notice that as well.  Must be the GUI programmer in me, but I resisted commenting (until now).  :)

Comment: @Sam: Hehe your resistance is better than mine. Mine appears to be ... well, futile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create and array and return the array?

```
$id_list = array();
foreach($query->result_array()  as $row){
    $id_list[] = $row['departement_id'];
}

return $id_list;
```

Comment: This sounds like the most flexible solution.  This allows the caller to do whatever it wants with the data rather than narrowing it to just printing (unless that is the only purpose...).